# Ways to make ASP.NET build faster

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, optimization, compilation

When I'm building my web project it takes about 20 seconds to compile. Then when I try to browse to a web page in project, asp.net does its runtime compilation(another 20 seconds).  I know I can't escape these steps because thats how asp.net works, just want to see if anyone has some kind of optimization to make these builds faster.

Trying to improve my [Edit-Compile-Test loop](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000023.html)

My machine details:

-Intel Core i7 processor @2.80GHz  
 -8GB of RAM 
 -HD @ 7200 RPM

Comment: you can skip the runtime compilation step by using pre-compilation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx

Comment: Mine has gotten so slow that I'm about ready to open a technical support incident with MS.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a faster machine?  Sounds like a smart answer.  I know that the compiler can take advantage of multi core machines.  Also, during compilation there's a lot of Hard drive access, so it may make sense to get a solid state drive.  Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but it's a definite solution.

The other thing you can do is configure your project to allow for "Edit And Continue".  This will allow for small things to be change, and continue debugging, without doing a full recompile.

Comment: Annoyance with E&C: Web Dev server likes to pop up a notification every time you continue, and the port # keeps changing.

Comment: I'm using VS.Net 2008. It allows you to assign a specific port.

Comment: Good tip, thanks!  Still can't edit can continue with labmdas, but I guess that's better than nothing.

Comment: Would it make sense to get an external SSD or a memory stick, put all of my source code on that and run it from there?

Comment: If you hooked up an external SSD with eSATA or USB 3, it would probably give you speed improvements.  A regular memory stick (thumb drive), even the ones that say they are fast, are still quite a bit slower than a regular hard drive.  If you're going to get a real SSD, you might as well put it in the computer, but if you really want to carry it around, I would think that eSATA or USB3 should be fast enough.  USB2 maybe be too slow, and also it taxes your processor.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of thoughts:

- Disable any "realtime" virus / malware protection, at least during this process.
- Disable indexing (Windows, Google desktop, etc.) for the folders that VS uses during this process.
- Disable / stop other processes that may be accessing the hard disk. The biggest issue here is latency - even if other applications are accessing / writing tiny files, it is the access time that kills speed.

As the original poster suggested, your biggest bang will come from hardware: get an SSD and a processor with at least 4 cores. If you were to buy 4 cheap 64GB SSD's and put them in RAID 0, you would be shocked at the difference and even discover that your CPU and RAM will suddenly become bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

Move your [code onto a RAMDisk, or buy an SSD drive.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499889/ssd-and-programming)

Answer (score 0):

Suspend Resharper - R# helps tremendously when you're just coding but *really* slows down the Edit-Compile-Test loop.